Name of this part of jet engine inlet

I can't find any name of it. I see it on some gas turbines but not all of them.
Edit: Found them, they are called struts.

No, I don't mean IGV.  IGV are more distingiushible and there are many more things to whole surronding. This one that I'm reffering to are more like support fins, for stabilization or additionall rigidity? I'm not sure, they are usually omited in any descriptions.

Like IGVs usually has some mechanism to change it's position. This on the other hand is for sure static also the air passages are huge between them as there is only 6 of that.

Those are the structural elements (struts) holding/supporting the cone in the middle in respect to the outer case. As a side effect they also straighten the airflow entering the compressor. On the Olympus (and most probably on other engines as well) they were also used to let hot air flow toward the cone for anti-icing purposes (A1 in the following cutaway - cutaway source):

In that cutaway it's also possible to see that the cone, in turn, holds the shaft (through the roller bearings) of the low-pressure compressor.

Thank you, that's an answer that i really looked for.

@AdamDutkiewicz: you're welcome
